How to Select Specific Ranges in Results
Is it possible to retrieve data based on your preferences? For example, I only need to display columns 1, 5, 8, 11, and 23.
function showInputBox(){

 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your rep name.",ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

if(input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
  var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var userSelectedRep = input.getResponseText();
  var newData = data.filter(function(r){ return r[23] == userSelectedRep});
  var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
  newWs.getRange(2, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);


}

I tried to use getRangeList, but it’s not working. I’m not sure if it’s possible. I’m just a newbie trying to add a script to my Google Sheets data.

You don't need getRangeList. You can filter the columns manually by extracting the required only the columns you want (1, 5, 8, 11, and 23).
function showInputBox() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your rep name.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
    var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var userSelectedRep = input.getResponseText();

    // Filter the data by the rep name in column 24 (23 in zero-index)
    var newData = data.filter(function (r) { return r[23] == userSelectedRep });

    // Extract only columns 1, 5, 8, 11, and 23
    var selectedColumns = newData.map(function (r) {
      return [r[0], r[4], r[7], r[10], r[22]];
    });

    // Create a new sheet and set the selected data accordingly
    var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
    newWs.getRange(2, 1, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);
  }
}


You can also do it like this var selectedColumns = newData.map(([a,,,,b,,,c,,,d,,,,,,,,,,,,e]) => {       return [a,b,c,d,e];     });

Thank you, @alizain, I really appreciate it. I have another question: how can I add headers to display categories like DATE, TOTAL, NAME, etc.? Right now, I can only see the results.

@UnknownUsers so to add headers, you could pretty much do something like:
`// Add headers
var headers = ["DATE", "TOTAL", "NAME", ...];
// Create a new sheet and set the data accordingly
var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
newWs.getRange(1, 1, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);
` Sorry about the comment formatting
